# Are there any places where utf8 vs. utf-8 vs. UTF8 vs. UTF-8 makes a difference?

Tags: php, python, mysql, html, utf-8

In many different code environments' official documentation I see UTF-8 expressed either as upper- or lower- case, and also with and without the dash. Are there any places where one or the other is important to use?

Some places where these strings are found include:

- The PHP manual in reference to header() arguments (HTTP headers)
- The PHP manual in reference to PHP function arguments
- The PHP manual in reference to internal configuration
- The MySQL manual in reference to configuration
- Python 2 code encoding declaration
- Bash locale configuration
- HTML meta tags
- XML doctypes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official [registry of encodings](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets) defines the names as case-insensitive and the spelling as UTF-8 (UTF8 isn’t even a valid alias). It is highly unlikely that any software that can deal with UTF-8 would not recognize the name UTF-8. So in all places, it is important to use UTF-8 and not UTF8.

Since the names are case-insensitive, documentation may use any casing. Software that imposes case restrictions on them would be seriously broken, and I don’t see why would assume that such software exists. Variation in documentation does not mean that some specific casing of letters must be used.

Comment: "UTF8" works fine in python `.encode()`. So not that important in "all places"

Comment: mySQL doesn't accept `UTF-8` with a dash. It expects `utf8` (but is case insensitive)

Comment: Thank you! This is quite what I needed to know!

Answer (score 8):

This is indeed wildly different. One place will accept only one form; the other place will only accept the other.

Listing here which is correct in which situation is not a good idea - it would be a huge and pointless open-ended list. Simply always look up in the respective documentation which form(s) is/are accepted for the specific situation.

Comment: @David why, exactly? Apart from the fact that it's indeed one to a borderline non-constructive question - it's the only answer I can think of.

Comment: Thanks. I do see that some places require one form, others another form, and most are tolerant. I am mostly interesting in knowing the non-tolerant places!

Comment: @dotancohen just look in the documentation. There is no real point in asking this as a Stack Overflow question. It would be a completely useless list with no practical purpose.

Comment: @dotan ...unless you have an actual use case for such a list, of course. But I really can't think of a valid one.

Comment: I daily move from PHP to MySQL to Javascript coding, often with some C#, Java, or Python thrown in and even Bash on a bad day! I find it a hassle to look up _each_and_every_time_ and I try to use the same format as the official documentation examples. If I could just replace everything with, for instance, `UTF-8` I would be a happy man!

Comment: @dotan I'm afraid you can't do that. :) At least not, for example, for mySQL. That's also why I don't understand how the IANA registry helps you - it says UTF-8 should always be written UTF-8 but we all know there are platforms that differ from that so what's the point?

Comment: @Pekka: That is exactly the reason that I posted this question! To know where the exceptions are.